# Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7 hangs (is not responding) when opening web.config file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I have just completed moving my C# ASP.NET web application from Visual Studio 2008 running on Windows XP to Visual Studio 2008 running on Windows 7.

I have noticed when I open my web application in Visual Studio 2008 and double-click on the web.config file to edit the file, that Visual Studio 2008 hangs (is not responding).

Am I missing something?  Is this a bug with Visual Studio 2008 running on Windows 7, and if so, is there a fix?

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards

Walter

Comment: Only an idea. Have you the SP1 installed?

Comment: No, I haven't installed it.  Sounds like a good idea.  I've just now discovered SP1.  I'll download it and give it a go.  Thanks.

Comment: not sure if there's a bug, but I've recently done the same as you and moved my winxp vs2008 app to win7 vs2008 and I didn't run into this issue. Does the app compile and run ok on the new setup?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  I've just installed the SP 1.  It didn't make a difference.

Hi Paul.  The application doesn't compile and run.  I think it completes the build OK, but it just hangs before starting up a web browser.  Any ideas?  Thanks.  Walter.

Comment: I also installed this HotFix:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958094

after SP1, but it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: maybe try renaming the old web.config file and then create a new you and see if you can edit that one? can you open and edit other project files?

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Other files open OK.  I have created a new web.config file and still VS2008 hangs when I try to open it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a new Hotfix from MS that is supposed to solve the problem: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB963035

This one has also been noted to solve related issues:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB960075

Answer (score 0):

I am running into a similar problem with VS 2008 and Windows 7 RTM. Al other apps work fine, when I go into VS 2008 and try to click on a file in an existing solution or trying to create a new solution it hangs.  I have to create winforms, wpf and a database solution.  Says creating xxx... hard drive is going nuts, cpu % is high.  But is non responsive, have let it sit for an hour with no difference (to create a new solution).

Installed VS 2008 SP1, and SQL Express SP1.  Running VS with the run as administrator option.  Have tried the compatibility options of Vista, Vista SP1 & Vistar SP2 all with same results. Have tried to repair install, uninstall and re-install.  Have tried both VS 2008 Pro and Team editions.  Worked fine previously with Windows 7 build 7168.